# Number of (cyclic) subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{30}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, direct-product

How many subgroups does  $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ have? How many of them are cyclic?

First, I would like to know, if this answer for the first part of the question is correct:

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{30}\cong \mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}\times\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ and that if the order of groups are coprime, the subgroups of the direct product are products of subgroups of the groups. So I can count the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$, $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ separately and multiply. The last two have just the 2 trivial subgroups.

I started counting the subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$ using Goursat's Lemma. I found 3 subquotients of $\mathbb{Z_2}$, two of them are zero and one is $\mathbb{Z}_2$. For $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ there are 15 subquotients which are isomorphic to one of $\{\{0\} (\text{appearing 5 times}),\mathbb{Z}_2 (\text{appearing 4 times}),\mathbb{Z}_4,\mathbb{Z}_8,\mathbb{Z}_{16}\}$. Now, I need to find isomorphism between the subquotients of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$. The only possible ones are the zero map between the zero groups and the identity on $\mathbb{Z}_2$. So there are $2\cdot5+1\cdot4=14$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

So in total there are $2\cdot2\cdot 14=56$ subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}\times\mathbb{Z}_{30}$?

Now, it comes to counting how many of them are cyclic. I have no idea how to approach this. I don't know anything about the cyclic subgroups of a product of two groups...
I can found some by hand (These which comes from a product of cyclic subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}_{16}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{30}$ which have comprime order (I found 23)). But I guess that are not all? Or if so, how do I know that?

Comment: Sorry, but what a tedious question! I cheated and did a computer calculation, which confirmed that your answer of $56$ subgroup altogether is correct. A key observation is that they are all cyclic except those that that contain the subgroup $N := Z_2 \times Z_2$, and the number of those is equal to the number of subgroups of $G/N \cong Z_8 \times Z_{15}$

Comment: @DerekHolt Yes I know, pretty ennoying, but it's in one sample exam fo an exam I prepare for, so I thought it might be better to know how to solve it... Thanks for confirming the first part! How did you observe that they are all cyclic except those that that contain the subgroup $N:=Z_2\times Z_2$?
And why is the number of those equal to the number of subgroups of $G/N$? It has $32$ subgroups? So there are $56-32=24$ cyclic subgroups? So I just missed one...

Comment: No, $Z_8 \times Z_{15}$ contains $16$ subgroups, leaving $40$ cyclic subgroups. All of the Sylow subgroups are cyclic except for the Sylow $2$-subgroup, which is $Z_2 \times Z_2$ so any noncyclic subgroup must contain that.

Comment: Oh yes of course, I messed it up...